# How to use Ternary Operator in JSP

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I have a query with regards to using Ternary Operator in JSP. The below mentioned code uses if else statement which works fine.

```
<%
                if ("Y".equals(TestPerformed)) {%>
            Test Performed <input type="checkbox" id="TestPerformed<%=RowCount%>" name="TestPerformed" value="Y" checked>
            <%} else {%>
            Test Performed <input type="checkbox" id="TestPerformed<%=RowCount%>" name="TestPerformed" >
            <%}%>
            <input type="text" id="HiddenTestPerformed<%=RowCount%>" name="TestPerformed" value="<%=TestPerformed%>"/>
            <script>
                $(function () {
                    $("#TestPerformed<%=RowCount%>").change(function () {
                        $("#HiddenTestPerformed<%=RowCount%>").val(($(this).is(':checked')) ? "Y" : "N");
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

But When I use the Ternary Operator it gives me a compile time error stating not a statement.

```
Test Performed <input type="checkbox" id="TestPerformed<%=RowCount%>" name="TestPerformed" value="Y" <%"Y".equals(TestPerformed) ? "checked":"";%>>
            <input type="text" id="HiddenTestPerformed<%=RowCount%>" name="TestPerformed" value="<%=TestPerformed%>"/>
            <script>
                $(function () {
                    $("#TestPerformed<%=RowCount%>").change(function () {
                        $("#HiddenTestPerformed<%=RowCount%>").val(($(this).is(':checked')) ? "Y" : "N");
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

The Above code basically checks if the TestPerformed is Y or N. If its Y then the Checkbox will be checked or else it will be unchecked.
The Jquery is used to change the value of the HiddenTestPerformed input to Y or N.

Kindly help me out as in How do I use this Ternary Operator to fulfill this requirement.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think you want:`<%="Y".equals(TestPerformed) ? "checked":""%>` not `<%"Y".equals(TestPerformed) ? "checked":"";%>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are just missing an equals in the scriplet, also some how you need to insert in (brackets) the whole expression and you dont end with a `;`

Finally `<%= ( <expression> ? <then_String> : <else_String> ) %>`

```
<input type="checkbox" id="TestPerformed<%=RowCount%>" name="TestPerformed" value="Y" <%=("Y".equals(TestPerformed) ? "checked":"")%> >
```

Comment: Thanks JoyBlanks. It really worked. Thank you very much